# Is there a way to create a keybind that writes text in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext

I want to make it so that if I press **ctrl+alt+t**, Sublime Text will write a template like this for my comments:

```
# -----  -----
```

I know **ctrl+/** makes/toggles comments, but I mean a keybind that will add this exact template.

An example

[image: 1]

Another example

[image: 2]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with two features of Sublime: [Snippets](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/completions.html#snippets) and [Key Bindings](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/key_bindings.html). Use the Tools > Developer > New Snippet… command to create a snippet. Enter your template text in the snippet, like so:

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
# ----- ${1:NAME} -----
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <!-- <tabTrigger>hello</tabTrigger> -->
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.python</scope>
</snippet>
```

Save the snippet in your [User package](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/packages.html#special-packages). Then, create a key binding to trigger the snippet:

```js
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+t"],
    "command": "insert_snippet",
    "args": {
        "name": "Packages/User/comment-section.sublime-snippet"
    }
}
```

Note that, using this approach, you will need multiple snippets depending on the scope. (E.g. JS files need slash comments.) One solution here is to set a scope (with `"selector"`) on the key bindings.

For more details and variations (file snippets vs inline, for example), see this discussion on the [Sublime Forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-to-bind-snippets-to-key-combo/1330).

Comment: Brilliantly said. Thank you loads. I did not know that there was a forum for Sublime Text as well and I recommend others to use it.